# using SSL on a subdomain that points to an EC2 instance

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, dns, subdomain

I'm pretty new to Amazon instances so any help or advice would be appreciated

We host our own webserver, ourdomain.org, that has several subdomains. 
One of these subdomains, sub.ourdomain.org, is actually pointing to an amazon EC2 instance. 
The instance is reached through a DNS A record.

Everything is working fine but now we want to use SSL.

My question is where to install the certificate and how to configure it. I'm thinking we want to do this on the amazon instance but I'm worried that the certificate will be invalid because the domain the EC2 instance is part of will be different from our webservers domain. Will this be an issue? Are there other potential issues I'm missing

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to use SSL for all sites under ourdomain.org or only for sub.ourdomain.org?

Comment: not all sites under ourdomain.org need SSL but for sure more than just sub.ourdomain.org

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install the SSL cert/private key on the EC2 instance (your webserver: apache, nginx, etc.) Make sure the certificate domain matches exactly `sub.ourdomain.org` or it's a `star` certificate meaning `*.ourdomain.org`