# Setting up SSL on EC2 instances (FQDN)

Tags: rest, ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2, https

Sorry if the question is too basic.

I want to set up SSL on my EC2 instance, let us say foo.us-west1.compute.amazonaws.com. And I want to create a record set of type A to point a subdomain at my EC2 instance, let us say sub.foo.com. When I am creating a SSL certificate, which one of the two domains do I have to use?

I'll be saving the certificate and key on the ec2-instance and be configuring NginX to use those keys.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: How is not covered under "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"? This is a valid devops question I'm sure someone will have at some point.

Comment: There are similar questions asked on stackoverflow anyway, like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127925/using-ssl-on-a-subdomain-that-points-to-an-ec2-instance?rq=1... its not very different and 7000 people have opened that question for a reason. So thanks for your opinion but I think its a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject of the certificate must match the domain from the URL used to access the site. Neither IP address matter nor DNS domain alias (CNAME) - all what matters is the domain name used in the URL since this is used by the client to verify the certificate.

Comment: I am setting up a rest api using express... and I will separately host the client side. So I'm guessing you mean api.domain.com will be the subject of the certificate? I'll be exposing the API through api.domain.com...

Comment: @MananMehta: *"I'll be exposing the API through api.domain.com... "* - in this case the domain of the URL is api.domain.com and thus should be included as subject in the certificate.